# How to insert the output of SHOW ERRORS statement output into a custom log table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am new to mysql. I have a log table created now I want to insert the output of SHOW ERRORS message into a log table so that I can keep a track of failures in future.
Can you help me achieve this in mysql

Comment: How do you execute the `SHOW ERRORS` statement ? Please post some code as [example]. We also need the schema of your _log table_ (e.g. its CREATE TABLE statement).

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`#####`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_proc`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS;        
        insert into db.logtable(RunID,Message,Logtype) select (RuniD, @message,'Error');
        ROLLBACK;   
    END;

Comment: here I want to insert the output of show errors into a log table